# aggregate a column based on the another columns' values count in pyspark dataframe

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, hive

I would like to do some aggregations for a pyspark hive table.

my table:

```
  id   value_tier ($)
  105   5
  117   5
  108   10
  110   12
  105   10
  112   10
```

I need to get the number of ids that only appear in one "value_tier".

```
value_tier   num
   5          1 -- for 117
   10         2 -- for 108 and 112
   12         1 -- for 110
```

Here, 105 is not counted because it appears in two value_tiers.

```
    5 and 10
```

My sql DDL works but long and ugly.
I would like to have one more elegant.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DataFrameAPI use **`groupBy`** and **`agg`** with **`collect_list`** function.

```
df1.show()
#+---+----------+
#| id|value_tier|
#+---+----------+
#|105|         5|
#|117|         5|
#|108|        10|
#|110|        12|
#|105|        10|
#|112|        10|
#+---+----------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1.groupBy("id").
agg(concat_ws(',',collect_list(col("value_tier"))).alias("value_tier")).\
filter(size(split(col("value_tier"),",")) <=1).\
groupBy("value_tier").\
agg(count(col("id")).alias("num"),concat_ws(",",collect_list(col("id"))).alias("ids")).\
show()
#+----------+---+-------+
#|value_tier|num|    ids|
#+----------+---+-------+
#|         5|  1|    117|
#|        10|  2|112,108|
#|        12|  1|    110|
#+----------+---+-------+

#use collect_set to eliminate duplicates
df1.groupBy("id").
agg(concat_ws(',',collect_set(col("value_tier"))).alias("value_tier")).\
filter(size(split(col("value_tier"),",")) <=1).\
groupBy("value_tier").\
agg(count(col("id")).alias("num"),concat_ws(",",collect_list(col("id"))).alias("ids")).\
show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can use `not exists` and aggregation:

```
sélect value_tier, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
where not exists(
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.value_tier = t.value_tier and t1.id <> t.id
)
group by value_tier
```